# Combine Observables after subscribed

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

Is it possible to `merge` an `Observable` to another after a subscription was made, so the `Observer` can see the result?

I know this doesn't work, but I mean something like this:

```
observable.subscribe( (i) -> doSomething(i) );
observable.merge(anotherObservable);
```

And then `doSomething` will receive the values of `anotherObservable` as well.

Also, is it there a way to keep merging, even if all merged `Observables` already completed?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why do you want this and why can't you specify what to merge upfront? You could merge a `PublishSubject<Observable<T>>` and keep adding more sources via its `onNext`.

Comment: I have some sequences that will appear on runtime randomly... I want to combine them into one sequence, for a one single consumer

Comment: To be more specific, I have some network connections that give their status as a sequence, so multiple network connections will generate multiple status sequences... I want to combine those network status into one general Application Status... Thus I want to merge sequences that can appear from the nowhere, even if other previous sequences have completed

Comment: You can still do it before subscribing. Use Relay/Subject to emit "sequences that can appear" and merge emitted items.

Comment: The whole idea is to have it dynamicly after subscription already occurred. It was a Network Status watcher, but this was 2 years ago.